# Dart Ubuntu Server 14.04 how to install missing library for Dartium

Tags: ubuntu, installation, dart, dartium

I'm attempting to port a dart project from Ubuntu 12.04 to another machine with Ubuntu Server 64 bit 14.04.  I installed a new version of Dart Editor, etc. and copied my code over.

So far it appears to work except when I attempt to run the web code in Dartium.  I receive an error message that my machine needs to be prepared for Dart - specifically it can't find ***libudev.so.O***.

How do I install that.  I'm using a minimal Gnome GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That version of `libudev` is not shipped with Ubuntu 14.04. You can try to create a symlink to the new version and see if it works:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0
```

Or you can download that package from http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libudev0 (12.04 version) and install it in your system. I have not tried it, but as this package basically only contains libudev0 library itself and a symlink, it should work as well.